# How to best manage tables in HTML?

Tags: html-table

What's the best way to manage tables or tabular data in HTML? Is there a fast way (app/plugin) to reorder rows/colums/etc. It seems very cumbersome to do by hand inside the code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to manage tables is by using an html editor such as Microsoft Expression Web or Adobe Dreamweaver.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver, but it won't let me reorder rows by just dragging unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Unfortunately most HTML editors have limited features. What you need is a wysiwyg editor. You can try using Microsoft Word to manipulate your table with drag-and-drop feature and save as HTML file. However, your code can become pretty complex.

Comment: Thanks, but is there really no easier or rather more professional way to manage tables than using Word? Not even Google Docs let's you output a Sheet as a HTML Table.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no software out there yet that has all the features you're looking for as far as I know. You can try doing more research but most HTML editors are for coders which gives you more control to how your web page looks and behaves.